# Как проверить email на существование без фактической отправки на него письма

Tags: алгоритм

Мне в программе нужно написать проверку email-адреса на существование. Но я совсем не представляю как работают почтовики.

Требования: проверить адрес на существование без фактической отправки на него письма с максимальной точностью. Если адрес точно существует то так и сказать, если адрес точно не существует то так и сказать, если по полученным данным нельзя достоверно определить - существует или нет то тоже так и сказать.

Если достоверно определить - существует email или нет в принципе невозможно но можно точно определить, что он не существует то логика следующая:

- Если адрес точно не существует то так и сказать;
- Если нельзя точно сказать, что адрес не существует но он не прошел большинство проверок то тоже сказать, что он не существует;
- Если большинство проверок пройдено то сказать, что существует;
- Если же что-то непредвиденное случилось (например - почтовик лежит и тупо не отвечает на запросы) то сказать, что не удалось проверить.

Хочу понять алгоритм, как это сделать.

Comment: @РашенБеар, https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6650-PHP-Check-if-an-e-mail-is-valid-using-SMTP.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, я бы озадачился получением MX из DNS для домена, а потом бы пробовал пройти SMTP-протокол до `RCPT To:`. Хотя в RFC и описана специальная команда проверки существования адреса `VRFY`, кажется - она слишком часто не реализована.

Словом, примерно такой алгоритм - по MX-записям в порядке приоритета SMTP-соединение, проверка `VRFY`. При несработке - начало сессии - `MAIL From:`, `RCPT To:` - в общем, до `DATA`. По каждой команде смотреть ответ.

Ну, а по ответам судить о происшедшем.

Надежность не 100%, но тем не менее... Есть вариант и нарваться на ложный положительный ответ - правда, сейчас таких релеев почти нет - когда один сервер готов принимать почту для домена и переправлять на него - но теоретически при этом имеется несоответствие RFC, так что такое встречается редко.

Да, это все - из практики, но практики примерно 7-8-9-летней давности, последние тенденции в этой области как-то не отслеживал...

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321

Comment: стоит явно упомянуть что "максимальная точность" без фактической отправки письма может быть не слишком большой, можно сказать бесполезной во многих случаях (ответ на `rcpt TO:` может быть положительным для заведомо несуществующих адресов). В частных случаях можно через восстановление пароля сервиса попробовать или новую учётную запись создать.